# Bootstrap 3 navbar collapse not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a simple navbar that collapses for mobile viewers. The icon appears when the page reaches a small width, but upon clicking the button, it will not expand.

```
<div id="headerfront" class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="" class="navbar-brand" ><img id="logo" src="images/brand.png" height="44px" width="146px" /></a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" ></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#" class="" >Sign In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="" >Sign Up</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the links and scripts in the head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/boostrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More likely you miss bootstrap js file please replace your line

```
<script src="js/boostrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much for taking the time to help a novice!