# Bootstrap 3: navbar collapse collapsing but not expanding

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, hamburger-menu

I am building a fairly simple static website with Bootstrap 3.

In terms of navigation, I need a full-width navbar on desktop and a "hamburger" menu on mobile.

So I went with Bootstrap's navbar-collapse:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right press">
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="index-FR.html"><img src="images/FR-flag-icon.png" alt="French Version" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/US-flag-icon.png" alt="English Version" /></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

As suggested in many other similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722263/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse-not-expanding) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770164/toggle-button-collapse-not-working-in-bootstrap-navbar), I DID check that I had the latest Bootstrap JS file included, with the following line between my `<head></head>` tags:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

—————

**UPDATE**: I also have the following inludes in my `<head></head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <!-- web-font -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,100,200,300,500,600,' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.wordrotator.css">       
        <!-- web-font -->
        <!-- js -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="email, productivity app, iphone app, clarity, peace" />
```

In addition, below the above code, I also have some custom JS scripts.

—————

**UPDATE 2**: here are my browser console logs:

```
http://localhost:8888/timyo/js/move-top.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/timyo/js/easing.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher
http://localhost:8888/timyo/images/themes.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
base.js:1624 SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
```

—————

However, when I am in my browser, and I resize the window, the navbar will turn into the hamburger menu, but the hamburger menu is not clickable and does not expand.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you include jQuery? https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Comment: It works. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/meuw590o/)

Comment: @GerritBertier Yes, I have. See the code in the **UPDATE** section of my question.

Comment: @alirezasafian Interesting. On my local machine, both directly in Chrome and through http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ it does not work. Is that possible that one of my other scripts is messing with Bootstrap JS?

Comment: Check your browser console.

Comment: Done. It seems I get many errors but the one causing the problem is the one about the wrong version of jQuery, isn't it?

Comment: I just update the code with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>` and now it works perfectly well. Thanks a lot for your help. Feel free to suggest this as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher
```

I simply updated my  section with:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to also load the Bootstrap CSS theme, minified or full:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Reference the Getting Started here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have Bootstrap CSS loaded (see the **UPDATE** section of my question). Any other idea?